# How to add Pointer to a class in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a bit new in c++ programming. I would like to get some help on how to properly add a pointer to a defined class, to access the memory address of the object **Rectangle**.
    I have been asked to add a pointer to this code, I have tried adding it, but I get the following error

> expected a member name.

I'm not sure where is the problem.

```
class Rectangle
{   
public:
    float width;
    float height;
};


int main()
{
    system("color 2b");
    cout << "This program will calculate area and perimeter of a rectangle.\n";

    Rectangle rect;
    Rectangle *ptrrect; 

    ptrrect = &rect;

    cout << "Access the member of Rectangle: " << ptrrect->.rect() << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the height: \n";
    cin >> rect.height;

    cout << "Please enter the width: \n";
    cin >> rect.width;


    cout << "The area of the rectanlge is: " << rect.height * rect.width; 
    cout << " The premiter of the rectangle is: \n" << (rect.height * 2) + (rect.width * 2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line did did the compiler say "expected member name" error was in? It usually says it before or after "expected member name"

Comment: I am getting all kinds of other errors in that code, but not the one you mentioned (both `g++` and `VC++`)

Comment: which triangle are you talking about????

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2015, it is on line 28

Comment: @user5499016 which line is line 28?

Comment: Hi, I think I got it working,
@jipr311 sorry that was just an typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptrrect->.rect()` in particular seemed to be a problem as I don't see a function called `rect`

also the `->` accesses a member of a pointed object, while `.` accesses a member of just the object so if you should use -> if the variable whos member you are trying to access is a pointer, and `.` if it is just an object.

So if you wanted the width of `rect` you would use either `rect.width` or `ptrrect->width`

`ptrrect->.rect()` is trying to point to a function called rect() in rect, which does not exist. And as I said before take out the `.` `ptrrect->rect()` would probably work if you had a function called rect() within the  `class` `Rectangle`

Comment: Yes that will delete just the pointer, but not the thing it points to